# Change firebase realtime database node after 5 minutes on inactivity using cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In my firebse realtime database i have longitude and latitude nodes under each user, what i want is to reset longitude and latitude if they did not change for a while (5 minutes for example) using the cloud functions

```
|
 -- users
     |
     --IyH8xhaI2bS82twAlJsYa5gFvRg2
           |
           |----longitude : xx.xx
           |----latitude  : yy.yy
```

Comment: You could schedule a function to run every 5 minutes to check the data.  Is there a specific problem you're having implementing this?  What you're asking right now is a bit broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The schedule function can't check when the data last changed, i need it to detect if the data did not change for 5 mins for example and then delete it.

Comment: Yes, you can arrange for that comparison by storing the last observed values in another part of the database.